# Excel VBA macro to delete duplicate rows based on multiple columns and sum another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet. It has data in columns A through J.

I want to write a macro that will find duplicate rows based on columns A through I.

This means two rows should be considered duplicates if the values in all the columns A to I are duplicated.

Out of duplicate rows, the macro should

1) Add the values in column J. The column J contains numbers.

2) Retain one row and delete its duplicates.

3) In the retained row, update the value in column J with the sum calculated in step 1.

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: I am not sure your question is specific enough. Can you show your code so far, and explain what part is not working?

Comment: You could make use of an extra column in which you concatenate rows A-I and make a loop using a countif formula with a dynamic range. When there are other values below, retain the row and change J. Use another countif formula which only looks at cells above. When there are values above, delete the row. I hope this can help you a bit further.

Comment: Also when you delete rows in a loop, make sure you loop reverse; go from the last cell to the first: `for i = lastrow to 1 step -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the sum totals into an array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dedupeSumK()
    Dim i As Long, lrK As Long, tmp As Variant, vals As Variant

    With Worksheets(1)
        tmp = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim vals(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), 1 To 1)
        For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            vals(i, 1) = Application.SumIfs(.Columns(11), _
                                            .Columns(1), tmp(i, 1), _
                                            .Columns(2), tmp(i, 2), _
                                            .Columns(3), tmp(i, 3), _
                                            .Columns(4), tmp(i, 4), _
                                            .Columns(5), tmp(i, 5), _
                                            .Columns(6), tmp(i, 6), _
                                            .Columns(7), tmp(i, 7), _
                                            .Columns(8), tmp(i, 8), _
                                            .Columns(9), tmp(i, 9), _
                                            .Columns(10), tmp(i, 10))
        Next i
        .Cells(2, "K").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals

        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```